# Flask db migrate stops working on a new ec2 machine

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, flask, flask-migrate

So this is a bit weird.  I took an image of my dev server (ec2), spooled it up onto a new machine, and all of a sudden "flask db migrate" stopped working for me.  It now returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/flask", line 7, in <module>
    from flask.cli import main
ImportError: No module named cli
```

I'm not particularly sure how to go about debugging this.  A little guidance would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: try reinstalling flask

Comment: I actually did that.  No change.  Also, thanks for the comment!

Comment: @Miguel any thoughts on how to go about debugging?  I'm not sure how where to look or tell what's going on.  I can still run my application, I can import flask_migrate, I just cannot run python -m flask or the script

Comment: did you do a clean install? I.e. did you use a new virtualenv, or remove the current version of flask before reinstalling? It looks like your virtualenv is not in a good shape, a part of flask seems to be missing.

Comment: I did a pip install flask -I --force-reinstall

Is there another technique that is better?

Comment: AH, i dug into the libs some more, and yup, there was an old library in there as well.  Removed it.  Good to go.  Thanks for the help miguel!